# How can I edit ORB parameters in OpenCV 3.0.0 and higher OR use different OpenCV versions in the same app in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am implementing an algorithm for which I require [CLAHE](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/CLAHE.html) and to change [ORB parameters](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3167/java-how-to-set-parameters-to-orb-featuredetector/). The ORB parameters I change in Java/android for version below 3.0 as described [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/76074/send-parameters-to-orb-feature-detector-android/). The OpenCV library doesn't have a constructor implementation for CLAHE in version lower than 3.0. for android. So, unfortunately, I don't know how to do it. What I can think of is doable is writing one part in C++ and port it to Java but that is pretty complex. May be changing the function names in OpenCV library is also possible, but I would prefer not to mess with the libraries. Can anyone suggest a possible method/solution?

Comment: Do **all** your processing in C++ with OpenCV 3.1, and then call the function `doAllProcessing` from Java with a JNI call

Comment: Yes that is also possible, but does coding in C++ for android have any other advantages over coding in Java?

Comment: Well, considering that OpenCV is native in C++, your code get compiled native, and you don't have to rely on a _incomplete_ wrapper and you can use all the power of OpenCV... then yes... there are some advantages

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just another thing, I got a workaround by just calling another app which implements CLAHE only and pushing the result. Is it better yet to move to C++? (Its a large app, moving to C++ would be time taking even though I have all the right reasons!)

Comment: It's up to you. In the long term it's probably better.

Comment: @Miki Do you know if it is possible to change ORB parameters in OpenCV 3.0 and above?

Comment: [yes](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d95/classcv_1_1ORB.html)

Comment: I meant for java. Porting the code into c++ is a pain in the ass!

Comment: I think that working in Java is a pain in the ass ;D However, I can't tell for Java.. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for someone who might bump into this problem in future and/or doesn't want to use C++ on android, from OpenCV 3.0 the parameters in Java (android sdk) can't be changed. As described [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/76074/send-parameters-to-orb-feature-detector-android/)